# RedHat global vimrc does not work

Tags: rhel, vim, vimrc

I wanted to setup global vimrc. But it does not work. I have it setted up in `/usr/share/vim/vimrc` where I have this config.

```
colo torte
syntax on
```

what I am doing wrong if the color scheme is not working for users?

Comment: Are all users using the same `vim` installation?

Comment: Yes they are using it

Comment: `strace` suggests to me vim looks at `/etc/vimrc` (only) for global configuration, but I don't know enough about vim to tell if that should load `/usr/share/vim/vmrc`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Red Hat has the global resource file in `/etc/vimrc`.

It can verfied with:

```
$ strace -eopen -o log vim test
$ grep vimrc log
open("/etc/vimrc", O_RDONLY)            = 3
open("/root/.vimrc", O_RDONLY)          = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/root/_vimrc", O_RDONLY)          = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```